# PDF content inside XML response file

Tags: c#, xml, pdf

I receive XML file that includes PDF content:

```
<pdf>
<pdfContent>JVBERi0xLjQKJaqrrK0KNCAwIG9iago8PCAvV.......
```

How can I save the content into PDF file?

I'm using C# 4.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That string value is the PDF in base64.  If you convert the base64 to a byte array you can just write that byte array to disk.

[Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx)

```
var buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(xmlStringValue);
File.WriteAllBytes(yourFileName, buffer);
```

Comment: So I put the same answer as everyone else and get down voted... sweet.

Comment: Thanks, you're the only one who provided sample code that I can start off with.

Comment: No problem, in the future you might add more details such as how you are reading the XML.  This could get even better ideas on how to access the information you want.

Answer (score 1):

It seems encoded with [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), But not sure. if it is, you can take that long string and convert with the function [Convert.FromBase64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx). You will obtain a `byte[]` that you can save as the actual pdf.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the pdf content is encoded in base64. You will have to decode it and save it to a file.

Edit: indeed, when I use base64 to encode a pdf file, the first few characters are JVBERi0x...